# How to check if an Excel spreadsheet is running, use it in an if command and run the sheet if it isn't already running

Tags: batch-file

I have been trying to set something up using batch. What I have been trying to set up is something that would open an excel spreadsheet containing some of the homework I had written up that I needed to get done. Though, I had run into a small problem when I had tried to check if the spreadsheet was open.  I tried looking at a few solutions to my problem but I never really understood how to use them or they weren't made for xlxs. What I currently have is this code:

```
@echo off
SET "stime=16:00:00.00"
SET "etime=24:00:00.00"
:start
IF %time% GEQ %stime% (
    IF %time% LEQ %etime% (
        START Homework.xlsx
        ECHO Hey
        GOTO start
    )
) ELSE (
    GOTO start
    )
IF %time% LEQ %etime% (
    IF %time% GEQ %stime% (
        START Homework.xlsx
        ECHO Hey
        GOTO start
    )
) ELSE (
    GOTO start
    )
```

Comment: You cannot use conditional operators with the non numeric characters in those variables. You will have to find another way.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do with the time comparisons.  Batch does not know anything about variable types.  Everything is a string unless you are comparing integers.  So you cannot compare dates or times unless you convert them into an integer it can compare.  If you are trying to see if a file is open or not you can use this. `2>nul (  >>test.xls (call ) ) && (echo file is not open) || (echo file is open)`

Comment: @Compo ,Squashman comparing times in 24h format is completely valid provided you quote the strings as times earlier than 10 have a leading space. Comparing `LEQ 24:00:00.00` is superfluous as every possible time will be less.(23:59:59.99 being the greatest value before turning to " 0:00:00.00")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is your code is looping like a fork bomb, I guess you're trying to stop the loop by verifying if an instance of Excel is running.

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq EXCEL.EXE" 2>NUL | find /I /N "EXCEL.EXE">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" //commands here
```

It will check if any excel file open, running, or even previewed in preview pane.

Comment: No. This only checks if Excel is running. It does not check if Excel has a file open.